# does a number have a smaller divisor?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a function: `has_divisor_smaller_than(n, i)` which checks if n has a smaller divisor than i (!=1)

I need to do that without loops and by using recursion.

This is what I did so far, but it is not working:

```
def has_divisor_smaller_than(n, i):
    if i == 1:
        return False
    elif n % i == 0:
        return True
    elif has_divisor_smaller_than(n, i - 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Your program [is not working](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: AFAIK this works fine, unless you want `has_divisor_smaller_than(10, 2)` to be `False` (2 is not less than 2).

Comment: `elif n % i == 0: return True` isn't valid. Eg, if n=15 and i=3 that will return True, but 15 doesn't have a smaller divisor than 3.

Comment: yeah, i want (10,2) to be false...and this is what i cant figure.... thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The code as is should work. But you can even refine it further. Basically, you don't need last two else-ifs.

```
def has_divisor_smaller_than(n, i):
    if i-1 == 1:
        return False
    elif n % (i-1) == 0:
        return True
    return has_divisor_smaller_than(n, i - 1)
```

Now there are two ways you can handle the `smaller than` condition either take (n, i) and use i-1 for calculation as done above or pass (n,i-1) is in the function declared below.

```
def has_divisor_smaller_or_equal_to(n, i):
    if i == 1:
        return False
    elif n % (i) == 0:
        return True
    return has_divisor_smaller_or equal_to(n, i)
```

Comment: hey,thanks a lot... but i tried to call this function and i doesn't work. for example (6,2) returns True... while I need it to return False (1 doesnt count as a divisor)

Comment: Hi, @Hadar I have updated the answer. The function you posted checks divisor less than or equal to. So you need to do an extra -1 internally/externally which is what I have done in the answer.